# Dockerizing multiple microservices in mono repository

Tags: node.js, docker

I want to dockerize a REST Api which uses multiple microservices. Most tutorials only cover very simple cases so I am a bit stuck about how to properly dockerize such a project.

**My project structure:**

- node_modules
- src

  - request-manager
  - request-worker
  - rest-api
  - shared
- test
- package.json
- tsconfig.json

So it has three microservices (request-worker, request-manager and the rest-api).

**My question:**

Is a .dockerignore and Dockerfile for each microservice necessary or how would one properly dockerize such a mono repository project?

Comment: If you haven't taken a look already - https://github.com/msanand/docker-workflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can** create one Dockerfile per microservice, but will probably have several conflicts and problems due to the fact that they are sharing multiple files (node_modules especialy).

I recommand use one (sub)repository for each service:

- request-manager

  - Dockerfile
  - src
  - node_modules
  - test
  - package.json
  - tsconfig.json
- request-worker

  - Dockerfile
  - src
  - node_modules
  - ...
- rest-api

  - ...
- shared

And be very careful at what you put in `shared` folder.

You also can use docker-compose for managing dependancies.